# Builds are always in "Queue" Status in Visual Studio 2010 (TFS 2010)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm new to TFS and have a big problem when I want to make builds in VS2010.

The builds don't run, they are always in Queue status (no error message). It's as if nothing happened. I searched all around the Internet and didn't find a solution to this problem.

The TFS Server is already configured (the Build agent and controller are successfully tested, MsDeploy full installed) and I have a public Drop folder (\MyServer\Drops  ==> C://Drops) on my server (configured with a domain account with full rights on the directory).

My goal is to build and deploy my .net MVC project via TFS on the server (win server 2008 r2).

I initially started  with this article :
http://vishaljoshi.blogspot.com/2010/11/team-build-web-deployment-web-deploy-vs.html

Could someone tell where the problem could come ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.. I just created a new Build agent.. with 2 build agents (only one used) my builds run ! (I dont know why..)

Comment: You have to use tags. In case of multiple build agents, you might have one build definition that is CI Build that validates your check-ins, then you can create a build agent on that machine and assign it the tag check-in. Then, you can set up the build definition to run only on a build agent that has the check-in tag. In similar way, you can have another build definition called Nightly Build. You assign it the Nightly tab and then set up the build definition to run only on a build agent that has this tag.

Comment: Same here. I needed 2 agents to run the builds. When using a single build agent I had a "Stop" icon in the TFS Administrator console. After adding a second one the lights are going green.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that Build Controller and Build Agent both are running successfully. Go to Team Menu in Visual Studio and Click on Manage Build Controllers. It will open Manage Build Controller window,checkthat both Controller and Agent shows ****Status** as **Available****.
[image]

Comment: Actually, my controller and agent where already "Available". As I explained, I just created another agent (not used) and It's OK..

Answer (score 0):

See the below code to check Queued Build status.

```
IQueuedBuild queBuild = buildServer.QueueBuild(request);
Console.WriteLine("Build queued...!");
while (true)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    queBuild.Refresh(QueryOptions.All);
    Console.WriteLine("Refreshed...!");
    if (queBuild.Status == QueueStatus.Completed || queBuild.Status == QueueStatus.Canceled)
    {
        break;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Build Completed...!");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the parameter "Maximum number of concurrently running builds" on the Build Controller Properties page. This instantly solved it for me. The default is the same as the number of enabled Build Agents, and "running builds" is apparently including queued builds. So adding agents will solve this but if the added Agents are not used its not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you having admin access on build server, open TFS admin console and restart your agent or controller services and try again.